# RxSwfit bind operation retain cycle

Tags: ios, memory-management, rx-swift, swift4.2, retain-cycle

I am new at rxswift framework.I have written a code below and I am not sure.Is there any retain cycle? Must I use weak reference to self?

```
    loginButton.rx.tap.bind {
        print(self.nameText.value ??  "")
       self.nameText.accept("ahmet vefa saruhan")
    }.disposed(by: disposebag)
```

second case is :

```
func myTestFunction(handler : () -> Void) {
    handler()
}

myTestFunction {
        self.isVisible = false
    }
```

is here any retain cycle problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, weak should be used when you using self inside block.
And use subscribe instead of bind.

```
basicLoginButton.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] () in
    print(self?.nameText.value ?? "")
    self?.nameText.accept("ahmet vefa saruhan")
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I think in the second case, everything is correct, there is not needed 'weak'.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have edited the question with part 2 :) in second example  , weak should be used?

Comment: also why I must subcribe it? it is same functionality

Comment: Thank you . I got it. İf closure stored in a variable, there is a retained cycle.